# What does array = anotherArray[anotherArray[i]] exactly do in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused what happens when we assign a value of array2 of index array2 of index i in array in for loop like that arr = arr2[arr2[i]]

For example, if my input is: int[] nums = {0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4};

Why is the output exactly like this: [0,1,2,4,5,3]

```
public static int[] buildArray(int[] nums) {
    int[] ans = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = nums[nums[i]];
    }
    return ans;

}
```

Comment: Evaluate it like you would any other expression. `nums[i]` evaluates to one number in the array, and then you have (for example, if `i` were `1`), `nums[2]`, which evaluates to `1`.

Comment: Ohh finally got it, was that simple, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`ans[i] = nums[nums[i]];` is just a different way of writing:

```
int num = nums[i];
ans[i] = nums[num];
```

but without using an extra, named variable.